# Looking for tools like PL/SQL Developer for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We're looking at migrating a project from Oracle to Postgres and I've been asked to provide a list of various tools that would be good to consider using. One we use regularly is PL/SQL Developer, which is a tool that lets you open DBs and tables, browse data, issue SQL queries, and view the responses. I'm not even sure what such a tool would be called other than a "browsing" tool, and searching Google has not been very fruitful. I'd like to get pointers to any such tools that we can look into.

A more general thing I'd be interested in is if there are sources of info on doing migrations that go beyond the SQL differences. Like, what tools (browsers, modelers, conversion tools, etc), books, training, etc., that a project might want to consider.

We've been using Oracle for so long, and that's all we know here.

Comment: Checkout pgadmin and datagrip

Comment: See the [Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)

Comment: pgadmin has a very similar feel to PL/SQL imo.